# How can I print data from my database while in QTableWidget?

Tags: python, sqlite, user-interface, pyqt4, qtablewidget

How can I print my data from my database (sqlite) into a notepad /word document from my table in my GUI (using the same formatting). Here is my code for the table which is represented on my gui.

```
class Table(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Table, self).__init__()
        with sqlite3.connect('database.db') as db:
            cursor=db.cursor()
            cursor.execute('select* from Receipt Order BY ReceiptID ASC')
            title = [cn[0] for cn in cursor.description]
            rows = [cn[0] for cn in cursor.description]
            cur=cursor.fetchall()
            layout = QtGui.QGridLayout() 
            self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
            self.setGeometry(500,500,500,400)
            qr = self.frameGeometry()
            cp = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
            qr.moveCenter(cp)
            self.move(qr.topLeft())
            self.label2=QtGui.QLabel(self)
            self.label2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('receipt_pic.jpg'))
            self.label2.setGeometry(0,0,500,400)
            self.table.setColumnCount(2)
            self.table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(title)
            for i,row in enumerate(cur):
                self.table.insertRow(self.table.rowCount())
                for j,val in enumerate(row):
                    self.table.setItem(i, j, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(val)))
            layout.addWidget(self.table, 0, 0)
            self.setLayout(layout)
            self.setWindowTitle('Receipt Table')
```

I want to be able to click a button which copies this information (which would appear as a table with filled columns and rows) into a seperate notepad file / or any text document (where I can send the table to the printer to be printed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be easier to just print the table directly, rather than use an intermediary file.

To do this, you can use a [QTextDocument](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextdocument.html) to create a printable representation of the table, and then use the built-in print dialogs to do the rest.

So, first add some buttons:

```
    ...
    layout.addWidget(self.table, 0, 0, 1, 2)
    self.buttonPrint = QtGui.QPushButton('Print', self)
    self.buttonPrint.clicked.connect(self.handlePrint)
    self.buttonPreview = QtGui.QPushButton('Preview', self)
    self.buttonPreview.clicked.connect(self.handlePreview)
    layout.addWidget(self.buttonPrint, 1, 0)
    layout.addWidget(self.buttonPreview, 1, 1)
    self.setLayout(layout)
    ...
```

then some handlers for the print and print-preview dialogs:

```
def handlePrint(self):
    dialog = QtGui.QPrintDialog()
    if dialog.exec_() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
        self.handlePaintRequest(dialog.printer())

def handlePreview(self):
    dialog = QtGui.QPrintPreviewDialog()
    dialog.paintRequested.connect(self.handlePaintRequest)
    dialog.exec_()
```

and finally some methods for creating the document and printing it:

```
def handlePaintRequest(self, printer):
    document = self.makeTableDocument()
    document.print_(printer)

def makeTableDocument(self):
    document = QtGui.QTextDocument()
    cursor = QtGui.QTextCursor(document)
    rows = self.table.rowCount()
    columns = self.table.columnCount()
    table = cursor.insertTable(rows + 1, columns)
    format = table.format()
    format.setHeaderRowCount(1)
    table.setFormat(format)
    format = cursor.blockCharFormat()
    format.setFontWeight(QtGui.QFont.Bold)
    for column in range(columns):
        cursor.setCharFormat(format)
        cursor.insertText(
            self.table.horizontalHeaderItem(column).text())
        cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.NextCell)
    for row in range(rows):
        for column in range(columns):
            cursor.insertText(
                self.table.item(row, column).text())
            cursor.movePosition(QtGui.QTextCursor.NextCell)
    return document
```

If you prefer to save to a file, you can use [QTextDocument.toHtml](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtextdocument.html#toHtml) to dump the table as html.

The printed results are quite basic, but if you want something more fancy, you can always build the document using html/css.

Comment: Thanks this works brilliantly! How would I have my columns show at the top of my rows of data?

Comment: @Jurisdiction. I've updated the example to add a bold header at the top of each page of the document.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function

```
    def LoadDatabase(self):
        self.banco = sqlite3.connect ( 'Vendas.db' )
        self.cursor = banco.cursor ( )
        query = "SELECT * FROM Produtos"
        result = self.banco.execute ( query )
        self.listaprodutos.setRowCount ( 0 )
        for row_number, row_data in enumerate ( result ):
            self.listaprodutos.insertRow ( row_number )
            for colum_number, data in enumerate ( row_data ):
                self.listaprodutos.setItem ( row_number, colum_number, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem ( str ( data ) ) )
```